# Why does Firefox show as my browser and not Tor?

Tags: firefox, support, browsers

Why does Firefox show as my browser when I access a site, such as AOL? I thought Tor *was* my browser. What does Firefox have to do with this site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tor isn't a web browser.
Tor is an anonymity network and can be used for things other than just visiting websites.

Tor Browser is a web browser. It's a fork of Firefox that's been modified and specially configured to run over Tor securely.

It's possible to use Tor with any web browser (at least in theory), but configuring your browser to use Tor *effectively* can be difficult and annoying, which is why Tor Browser exists.

Comment: Tor Browser is not just a specially configured Firefox. Firefox is not designed for anonymity, so Tor Browser is a fork of Firefox where the source code is modified to make it secure. Tor Browser claims to be "Firefox" however, to websites.

Answer (score 2):

Tor can work on both Firefox and Chrome. Its like an add-on and not a browser in and about itself.

You can also install a button on your chrome to toggle Tor on and off which is much quicker than launching Tor again and again separately.

[Here](http://www.takeaclick.com/how-to-guides/complete-updated-tor-guide-surf-internet/2071/) is a good guide on how to do it plus some more tips and explanations that will help you better understand how Tor works.

Comment: Doing this is possible, yes. But it is very important to understand that this will most likely not provide any anonymity. Browsers (Firefox/Chrome/etc) are not designed for anonymity, and just proxying them over Tor (or any other anonymity solution) will not prevent deanonymization attacks or leaks.

Comment: Please note that short URL's are discouraged. Please post full links. Also, if you're going to write a guide to it, please include the information in the answer itself instead of just linking to your website. Thanks.

Comment: So, if I choose Tor and make a request, why does a reply come back saying Firefox cannot deliver?